# Generating a unique hash for a custom structure?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashmap

I need to build a hash (as an unsigned 32-bit integer) for an object that encapsulate this data.

```
Entry {
    uint8 r;
    uint8 g;
    uint8 b;
    bool empty;
    uint8 count;
}
```

The hash must be unique for every instance, except if the instances are equal. Two instances are equal if and only if:

- count is equal in both instances

**AND**

- r,g,b are equal **OR** empty is set in both instances

The hash will be used in hashmaps and other containers so it might be called very often. The hash generation needs to be fast.

I thought about CCCERRRGGGBBB, where:

- CCC/RRR/GGG/BBB: count/r/g/b on 3 digits
- E: 1 if empty is set, 0 otherwise

But that number is way out of range.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a note:  most hashes don't guarantee absolute uniqueness, but are unique enough that the extra time to verify an exact match is negligible because it's basically O(1).

Comment: It's difficult or impossible to guarantee that the hash is unique for every instance, particularly when the size of the instance is larger than the size of the hash, as in your case: you're trying to fit each 33-bit value into a unique 32-bit variable.

Comment: Uniqueness is mathematically impossible in your case (because there are more different Entry values than possible numbers in a 32bit uint)

Comment: "Unique hash" is an oxymoron.  The only thing you can do is create a "hash" that is the concatenation of all the bits in your object, which is 33 bits.

Comment: Here's a thought: since oftentimes the blue value uses a smaller range than red or green (for instance, 8 bit assigns 3 bits to red and green and 2 to blue -- not sure if that's true in your case) you can take `b/2`, which can be stored in 7 bits. Then left shift and add them all together for 32 bits.

Comment: What does "empty" mean?  And can count ever exceed 127?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a tough time encoding 33 bits of information into 32 bits

```
if (empty == false)
  return count ~ r ~ g ~ b
else
  return count ~ 0
```

You get one overlap, which is when empty is false and r,g,b are all 0 - this will be the same hash as when empty is true and r,g,b are 0

Without further assumptions this is the best that can be done.

Comment: Very elegant. Another thought is to just drop the highest bit of count, and replace it with the bool. Then the overlap will only be between `count > 127` and `count <= 127`.

Comment: Great answer! I feel kind of stupid that I didn't realize my 33 bits of data couldn't fit in 32 bits... The count overlap is the best choice for me, count will never be over 100. It probably won't even be over 50. Thanks!